# Why is maven pointing to jdk 8 whereas JAVA_HOME points to jdk 11 on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu

I have downloaded on my Ubuntu machine the Java jdks 8 and 11 and are both inside the `/usr/lib/jvm` folder. Inside the `~/.bashrc` I have the following configurations:

```
# JAVA HOME
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.6
export M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.6/bin:/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin
```

despite that when I run `mvn --version` I get the following:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.6.3
Java version: 1.8.0_232, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.18.0-15-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Why is Maven not pointing to jdk 11? Does anyone know how I could fix this? Thanks in advance for your help